# Browsing Hdfs cluster from web application

Tags: java, hadoop

I want to browse Hdfs cluster from a Web application . How can I do that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can type in browser

```
 http://namenode:50070/
```

where namenode==ip address of machine at where namenode is runing...

so if you have single node cluster, you can just use

```
http://localhost:50070/
```

More Info - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-manage-view-web-interfaces.html

NOTE: these links will only work when hadoop cluster(namenode, datanode atleast) is up and running...